# Localhost test: can't get resource using http://localhost:8888

Tags: node.js, apache, port

For test purposes I run Apache local web server and I'm setting up a node.js app listening on port 8888 serving as image preprocessor, but unfortunately I'm experiencing problems as described below.

The node **app.js** is running in the web root directory:

```
'use strict';

let express= require('express')
    ,multer = require('multer')
    ,upload = multer()
    ,app = express()    

    //Import imgProcessor module which we would implement later
    ,imgProc = require('./imgProcessor');

app.get ('/', (req, res, next)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/appmain.html');
        });

app.post('/uploadImg', upload.array('pics'), 
        (req, res, next)=>{
            //Call the convertImgs method and pass the image files as its argument
            imgProc.convertImgs(req.files).then(
                (imageStringArray)=>{
                    //After all image processing finished, send the base64 image string to client
                    res.json(imageStringArray)})});

app.listen(8888, ()=>{
    console.log('Hosted on Port 8888')});
```

The **appmain.html** page resides in the same web root directory:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image Demo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <form id="form1" class="col m4 offset-m4" action="/uploadImg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="file-field input-field">
                <div class="btn">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <input type="file" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,png" name="pics">
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="progress" style="display:none">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row img-preview"></div>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#form1').on('submit', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var data = new FormData(this);
                    $.each(
                        $('input[name="pics"]')[0].files, 
                            function(i, file){
                                data.append('file-'+i, file);
                            });

                    $('.progress').css({
                            display:'block'
                        });

                    $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: $(this).attr('action'),
                            data:data,
                            cache:false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            success:function(data){
                                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                                    var template =
                                        '<div class="col m4">
                                         <div class="card">
                                         <div class="card-image">
                                         <img src="'
                                        + data[i] 
                                        + '"></div></div></div>';

                                        $('.img-preview').append(template);
                                }

                                $('.progress').css({
                                    display:'none'
                                });
                            },
                            error: function(err){
                                $('.progress').css({
                                    display:'none'
                                });
                            }
                        });
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use the URL `http://localhost:8888` in the browser the html page is loaded (i.e. I can see the buttons and input fields of the form) but the resources requested in the `<script>` (ex.: `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` or `node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js`) are not loaded. By the same way the page can't benefit from the unloaded CSS stylesheet.

As opposite, if I try to use the URL `http://localhost/appmain.html` the page is loaded as expected (I mean: with the correct resources and CSS).

It seems that my Apache Web Server can't serve resources when handling the port number inside the URL. How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**
Just to simplify: let'say the node **app2.js** is listening on port 8888 and it has just a method (get) that send to the client the 'Hello World!' page **app2main.html**. No files to serve. The app2main.html page need only to load a couple of Javascript script and a CSS stylesheet.

**app2.js**
    'use strict';

```
let express= require('express')
    ,app = express();


app.get ('/', (req, res, next)=>{
            res.sendFile(__dirname+'/app2main.html');
            });

app.listen(8888, ()=>{
    console.log('Hosted on Port 8888')});
```

**app2main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image Demo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script 
     src="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

    <body class="container">
        <h2> Hello World! </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

When accessing the URL `http://localhost:8888` the 'Hello World!' message appears, but I get the following error (visibile by inspecting the page):

```
http://localhost:8888/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Instead I get no error (and the expected style) when accessing the URL `http://localhost/app2main.html`

Comment: You can't serve random files from any old which place in a web app-you need to actually configure it to serve static files. Personally I wouldn't serve them from your node modules, though, why not build an app bundle?

Comment: Use relative path instead of absolute path in `appmain.html`

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for your reply and excuse me for my mis-explaining, but my question is _why_ I got 404 error related to GET of the script sources _only_ when using the port number. Please see EDIT example.

Comment: @MukeshSharma I tried to use absolute paths, with the same results. What I don't know is why the errors occur only when using port number in the URL.

Comment: I got your problem. You have to use `express.static`.  Just share the directory structure of your app.

Comment: `app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'))`

Comment: @MukeshSharma - Thanks! your suggestion solve the error. Unfortunately I cannot understand the port number role yet. I'll write here when I got the answer.

Comment: I didn't understand your port specific issue clearly. But I think, you are saying that when you use apache web server (http://localhost/app2main.html), you didn't get any issue, while you get issue with `node.js` app. Right?

Comment: If yes, then probably, because when you host static pages inside apache, then apache automatically resolves `src`, `href` to the files present in the directory, while in `node.js`, you have to mention those routes specifically, or have to use express.static. Hope I cleared doubt.

Comment: @MukeshSharma -  Sorry, you are right! The `express.static()` solution works well in both cases! Instead, before I got the errors only when using the `node.js` app (by specifying the port number), so I think your answer definitely solve my doubts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you should use `express.static` to serve static content in `node.js` app. In your case, your static content lies in `node_modules` directory itself. You can try the following code to load all resources,

e.g. http://localhost:8888/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'));
```

Also, you mentioned that when you access http://localhost/app2main.html, then it worked without `express.static`, because `apache` web server to serve static files similar to `express.static` in `node.js`. That's why
http://localhost/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js was working.

Hope it clears your doubt.